# Using php regex to translate output buffer, but not within HTML tags

Tags: php, html, regex

I have an array with strings to translate ($translation), and I want to use it to translate the output buffer. However, it should not replace within html tags. I have tried using php DOM, but this is too slow and probably too complex for what I want to do.

I currently use this code, but this of course also translates between tags.

```
$output = ob_get_clean();

foreach($translation as $original => $translated) {
    $output = str_replace($original,utf8_encode($translated),$output);
}
```

I guess I should use a regular expression to replace not within HTML tags, but I can't seem to find the correct expression to do this. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: You should translate phrases _before_ or while injecting them into the html markup. Doing that later only makes things much more complex and inefficient.

Comment: I know that is the proper way to do this, but I now have to translate some app that is already completely written, partially in flat html, so that is not possible

Comment: Then there is no way around a DOM parser.

Answer (score 0):

aside from opinions on the orginial idea:

i would not use regexp for that for performance reasen. you could utilize `strpos($html,'<')` + `strpos($html,'>')` in combination with `substr` to extract string by string.

But if somebody(including you) ever has to change the results at another point, then i suggest you go the extra mile and implement a 'proper' translation.

My recommendation:

1. look into [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php)
2. filter out the strings like mentioned above and generate a `.mo` -file
3. encapsulate the strings between the tags with the gettext-functions ([like here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.2/src/wp-includes/l10n.php))